# Copy and paste ImageSpan inside EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard, imagespan

i have an edittext which contains SpannableString with text and ImageSpan, i would like when i long press on an ImageSpan to know which Drawable i clicked (or the index in SpannableString) and convert it to uri to copy it to clipboard. after that you can paste it in the other edittext. but i don't know how to deal with this problem.

here is my code if someone can help, thanks in advance

```
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abcd efgh ijklmn opqr stuv wxy");
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logomakr);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 20, 21, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Copy Image")
                    .setPositiveButton("copy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with copy
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
    }, 20, 21, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setText(ss);
    editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```